# Latin name of "Roman Dodecahedron"?

Tags: word-request

There are some 200 archaeological finds known under the name  ["Roman dodecahedron"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_dodecahedron). There is no accepted or convincing explanation about their purpose and they have not been identified in any text. But, obviously, they have not been exceedingly uncommon, so perhaps there is some obscure word for them.

My guess is that they are some kind of  magical objects and that might be a clue where to look for a name fitting these artefacts .

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure this question is answerable, mostly because archaeologists have no idea what the things actually are!

Comment: There *are* some Latin words of unknown meaning, but any attempt to link one of them with an artifact of unknown name is arbitrary at best. You could, but nobody would be convinced until some new finding provides some more context.